# new line in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, solaris, sunos

I have the below command in my shell script to send all the four echo statements in one email

```
{
echo "Data Successfully loaded into LIP table"
echo "Total Items Purchased: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $1}'`"
echo "Total Items MissingorMismatch: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $2}'`"
echo "Error Percentage: $QUERY2" 
} | mailx -s "Report for $DATE_YEST_FORMAT1" -r rj@host.com user2@host.com
```

But when I see my email, I get the output like below which I don't want-

```
Data Successfully loaded into LIP table Total Items Purchased: 3956391 
Total Items MissingorMismatch: 975825 Error Percentage: 24.66452380464924
```

I need output something like below as line by line.

```
Data Successfully loaded into LIP table 
Total Items Purchased: 3956391 
Total Items MissingorMismatch: 975825 
Error Percentage: 24.66452380464924
```

Any suggestion why is it happening like this? I am running `SunOS (Solaris)`.

**Update:-**

After trying the suggestion give by `Kevin`

```
QUERY1=`hive -e "
set mapred.job.queue.name=hdmi-technology;
SELECT SUM(total_items_purchased), SUM(total_items_missingormismatch) from lip_data_quality where dt='$DATE_YEST_FORMAT2';"`

QUERY2=`hive -e "
set mapred.job.queue.name=hdmi-technology;
SELECT 100 * SUM(total_items_missingormismatch*1.0) / SUM(total_items_purchased) FROM lip_data_quality where dt='$DATE_YEST_FORMAT2';"`


mailx -s "LIP Data Quality Report for $DATE_YEST_FORMAT1" -r rj@host.com rj@host.com uname@host.com <<EOF
Data Successfully loaded into LIP_DATA_QUALITY table

Total Items Purchased: $(echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $1}')

Total Items MissingorMismatch: $(echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $2}')

Error Percentage: $QUERY2
EOF
```

**Output that I got in an email-**

```
Data Successfully loaded into LIP_DATA_QUALITY table

Total Items Purchased: $(echo 3712928   393455 | awk '{print }')

Total Items MissingorMismatch: $(echo 3712928   393455 | awk '{print }')

Error Percentage: 10.596892802661404
```

Which is not right.. I should be getting output like this-

```
Data Successfully loaded into LIP_DATA_QUALITY table

Total Items Purchased: 3712928

Total Items MissingorMismatch: 393455

Error Percentage: 10.596892802661404
```

I am running `SunOS`

```
bash-3.00$ uname -a
SunOS lvsaishdc3in0001 5.10 Generic_142901-02 i86pc i386 i86pc
```

Comment: FYI, you should use a heredoc for that input, rather than echoes like that.

Comment: can you show me one example? As I am new to shell script, so whatever easy approach I found, I did it like that..

Comment: Try using `printf` instead of `echo` and add a `\n` at the end of your string, e.g `printf "Data Successfully loaded into LIP table\n"`

Comment: What's your mail reader? If it's Outlook, look for an option "remove extra whitespace" (or something like that) and turn it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that `mailx` ignores single newlines and separates paragraphs by an empty line, similar to `tex` and our own SO.

That combined with a [heredoc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)

```
mailx -s "Report for $DATE_YEST_FORMAT1" -r rj@host.com user2@host.com <<EOF
Data Successfully loaded into LIP table

Total Items Purchased: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $1}'`

Total Items MissingorMismatch: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $2}'`

Error Percentage: $QUERY2
EOF
```

[It appears that your bash does not recognize the `$(command)` syntax, so I have removed that.]

[N.B. I just tested, and Solaris's `mailx` sent an email formatted precisely as I typed it. If your mail reader is displaying in HTML mode, however, it may collapse whitespace and show it all as one line.]

Comment: Thanks Kevin, But when I tried this thing in my Shell Script I got the result like this- `Data Successfully loaded into LIP_DATA_QUALITY table

Total Items Purchased: $(echo 3712928 393455 | awk '{print }')

Total Items MissingorMismatch: $(echo 3712928 393455 | awk '{print }')

Error Percentage: 10.596892802661404
` Which is not right. If you see my Output in the question which is different than yours, As echo also got printed in an email.

Comment: I also updated the question with the script and output I am getting. And what Output I should be getting.

Comment: That's odd, mine's interpreting variables and subshells properly. What shell are you using?

Comment: I am running `SunOS` and I am working bash shell. Updated the question as well with more details.

Comment: bash 3 may not have `$(...)`, try it with the backticks.

Comment: I was not able to understand. Can you edit your answer basis on what you said. As I am new to shell stuff.. So I am having hard time understanding the syntax..

Comment: Backticks are the subshell form you were using originally, see my update.

Answer (score 2):

Try to do it using `\n` as it is usually the standard escape sequence for a newline in a printing function., like so:

```
{
echo -e "Data Successfully loaded into LIP table\n"
echo -e "Total Items Purchased: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $1}'\n"
echo -e "Total Items MissingorMismatch: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $2}'\n"
echo -e "Error Percentage: $QUERY2\n" 
} | mailx -s "Report for $DATE_YEST_FORMAT1" -r rj@host.com user2@host.com
```

more info can be gotten [here](http://ss64.com/bash/echo.html).

Comment: This is not working.. I have already tried this. `\n` only doesn't works I guess. We need to add something more here.

Comment: In order for `echo` to process escape codes like `\n`, you must use `echo -e`. This is a Bash extension and is not portable across shells.  Using `printf` much more portable.